# Dynamic columns with equal height in a different rows wrapped in a single container

Tags: html, css

Please check the below code and the question

```css
.container_12 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid_4 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
}
.container_12 .grid_4 {
  width: 33.333333333333336%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_12">
  <div class="grid_4">Div 1</div>
  <div class="grid_4">Div 2 with extra content</div>
  <div class="grid_4">Div 3 with extra content</div>
  <div class="grid_4">Div 4</div>
  <div class="grid_4">Div 5 with extra content</div>
</div>
```

In the above code, **grid_4** is aligned 3 in a row, and remaining will wrap into the next row. These grid_4 are dynamically generated and even can be deleted. for example if i delete Div 4 and Div 5 move in to the place of Div 4 like the below code

```
<div class="container_12">
          <div class="grid_4">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid_4">Div 2 with extra content</div>
          <div class="grid_4">Div 3 with extra content</div>          
          <div class="grid_4">Div 5 with extra content</div>
        </div>
```

These div's are having different content and different height. So the question is how do i maintain a row height and 12/4 = 3 columns per row? This can be achieve by jquery by setting a height to the element. But is there any other possible way to achieve this by using only CSS [without flexbox - because of mobile compatability]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer [LIVE FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jtb1gf2t/2/) Just use jquery-2.2.4.min.js as extarnal resource and short your css section and use this script

```
var maxHeight = 0;

$(".container_12").each(function() {
 if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
  }
});

$(".grid_4").height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.. Is there any css only solution...?

Comment: that is the best solution for now. 
in css you can use flex but if you use flex after browser resize 2nd row will set different height which is max on 2nd row. 
or set a height value and make overflow: scroll but that looks ugly .

Comment: yes..but why we use jquery-2.2.4.min.js? In jquery 1.8.2 the max height always shows 0... Is there any possibility to achieve this with using jquery 1.8.2

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tjbaezid/jtb1gf2t/3/ try this here I use JQ 1.8.2

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 **`Flexbox`** was introduced just for this. It can handle responsive & complex layout by simplifying the code & increasing the readability without the use of any frameworks. It also works well with all the latest browsers including IE11, partial support with IE9, IE10. [here is the CanIUse link](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

You can easily achieve your solution by the below code:

```
.container_12 {
  display: flex; //initialises flexbox
  flex-wrap: wrap; //tells it to wrap overflowing contents
}
.grid_4 { 
  flex: 0 0 33%;
}
```

Its as simple as that.! [Codepen here](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/RGRAag)

Even better, this covers your dynamic height & width requirements. You can also go through the [`flex` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp)(shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`) to get to know more about "flexing" the dimensions of your divs

Comment: can i ask why the downvote ? have you even tried this or gone through flexbox?

Comment: May be flexbox is the solution.. but.. according to http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox it is only supported from android 4.4...below that we have to do some fallbacks...

Comment: So no support to android is a reason to downvote the answer ?! You "downvote" when the answer is not helpful, not because it does not support all the devices & browsers in the world - you can just mention that. That way almost every piece of front end code would not work on <IE8. so we downvote all the answers then? Please read the rules before you take impulsive decisions.